# rxjs collects the values sent by Subject and then sends the past values as an array

Tags: rxjs

rxjs collects the values sent by Subject and then sends the past values as an array

```js
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

const list$ = new Subject<number>();

list$
  .pipe(/* Which pipeline should I use to achieve the following log information */)
  .subscribe(console.log);

list$.next(1); // log: [1]

list$.next(2); // log: [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RxJS `.pipe()` is where you list a series of operators. Each operator is a pure functinon that receives the emitted value from the previous observable (or operator), and returns a new value for the next operator.

Because of the utility that operators provide, the subscription method can be kept rather simple, or completely empty.

Given your requirement to convert each emitted value to an array, I would recommend the `scan()` operator. Similar to `Array.reduce()`, the `scan()` operator gives you an aggregate value you can add to for each emission from the source observable (in this case, your subject).

```
const list = new Subject<number>();

list.pipe(
  scan((numArray, number)=>
    [...numArray, number], [] as number[]
  )
).subscribe(numArray=>console.log(numArray));

list.next(1); // [1]
list.next(2); // [1,2]
```

The reason I didn't include `$` in the variable name, is that this is typically reserved only for public observables (not subjects or subscriptions, which shouldn't be exposed to other classes/modules/files).

Answer (score 0):

I customized Observable to solve the problem, but I want to know how to use the `pipe` that comes with rxjs

```
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

const list$ = new Subject<number>();

var observable = new Observable((subscribe) => {
  const cache = [];
  const sub = list$.subscribe((v) => {
    cache.push(v);
    subscribe.next(cache);
  });

  return function unsubscribe() {
    sub.unsubscribe();
  };
});

const sub = observable.subscribe(console.log);

list$.next(1); // log: [1]

list$.next(2); // log: [1,2]
```